# Intellij Profiler - read/copy/save value

Tags: intellij-idea, profiling, profiler, hprof

In intellij profiler I try to read hprof file. There is a string which is very long and I can't read it, at least not all of it. There is a byte[] but it seems I would have to read/copy characters one by one...(which is not easy as I try to read query)

As I try to ctrl+c I can copy only part of it. Is there any way to copy or save it? (i mean every character not only part of it)

Edit:
I'd like to read my query which is too long to copy it(all I can do is copy it partially - it's not enough as I have other similar queries):
[image]

But I can only open it in a new tab and read byte[](like below)
[image]

Comment: See if `Ctrl A` (select all) works in your case.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I added some tags. If you are profiling Java code, you may want to add `java` tag as well.  See if you can your code that you tried.

Comment: Where in the Profiler window exactly do you want to copy values from? Can you update your question with a screenshot? There's also an existing feature request about adding the ability to flexibly copy&paste profiler values as text, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-244055. You can add your vote to it and leave a comment there describing your particular case.

Comment: @Koyasha, I've added it. It would be so nice if I at least could save these bytes to separate file...